# Python Variable Assignment on One line

Tags: python

Why does this:

```py
def make_fib():
    cur, next = 0, 1
    def fib():
        nonlocal cur, next
        result = cur
        cur, next = next, cur + next
        return result
    return fib
```

Work differently than:

```py
def make_fib():
    cur, next = 0, 1
    def fib():
        nonlocal cur, next
        result = cur
        cur = next
        next = cur + next
        return result
    return fib
```

I see how the second one messes up because at cur = next and next = cur + next because essentially it will become next = next + next but why does the first one run differently?

Comment: How about `next = result + next`

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes that would work but how does the first one differ from the bottom one though. Shouldn't cur, next = next, cur + next essentially be the bottom one?

Comment: the right-hand side is evaluated first, then applied. So essentially, both assignments happen "at the same time"

Comment: @njzk2 Ok so they happen at the same time. What do you mean by the right hand side is evaluated first. Can you use my example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cur, next = next, cur + next
```

is the same operation as:

```
# right-hand side operations
tmp_1 = next
tmp_2 = cur + next

# assignment
cur = tmp_1
next = tmp_2
```

Because the right-hand side is fully evaluated, and then the values are assigned to the left-hand side

Comment: ty for your explanation

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) is the documentation reference for that: "An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (… this can be … a comma-separated list, … yielding a tuple)." There is also a caveat for cases like `i, x[i] = 1, 2`.